# Recording and playing back sounds with LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

How do I record a sound to PCM format and replay it from there?

Comment: Check documentation https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Audio

Answer (score 1):

to record:

```
AudioRecorder recorder = Gdx.audio.newAudioRecorder(sampleRate, isMono);
short[] pCM = new float[1024]; // 1024 samples
recorder.readSamples(pCM, 0, pCM.length);
recorder.dispose();
```

to play back:

```
AudioDevice device = Gdx.audio.newAudioDevice(sampleRate, isMono);
device.writeSamples(pCM, 0, pCM.length);
device.dispose();
```